# With knockout foreach binding to TBODY, how to show loading animation during and AFTER ajax call

Tags: ajax, knockout.js, progress-bar

User makes repeated queries against database over the course of the day; each time, the  results are cleared from the table and new data are injected into the table:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: MyVM.Results">
```

and in code before the ajax call:

```
 MyVM.Results.removeAll();
```

I want to display an animated spinner of some kind while the ajax call is underway (Edit: and then also when ko is still working on creating the table rows after the ajax call returns).

EDIT: What is "the knockout way" of displaying this animation when there's a standard ajax call with fail and success callbacks, and the tbody is foreach-bound to the **observableArray** `Results`?

EDIT2:  configuring the Ajax call itself in jQuery with `beforeSend` and `complete` callbacks does not solve the problem entirely because taking UI action when the ajax call itself is complete does not account for the delay of knockout's for-each binding of the data to the table.  is there a knockout event that signals "binding complete"?

EDIT3: The answers are not understanding the problem. My fault for trying to make it simple and leaving out a lot of code.  This has nothing to do with Ajax. Consider this very simple scenario, which is *exaggerated to make the problem clearer*. Let's say you have an array with a million items in it. **Ajax call is already completed!**  Now you want to get the items in that array into a ko observableArray to which your TABLE TBODY is bound with for-each binding.   **This binding process itself is going to take some seconds to complete**  We want to hide our animation after the binding has finished and something is displaying on the HTML page.  Is there a way to know that the table rows created by knockout have begun to be rendered in the UI?

Comment: Can you post more code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Instead of **looping** through the Ajax data and adding an object to the ko observableArray on each iteration, I have to `pop` or shift() each item off the Ajax data array and push it onto the observableArray in a **custom event** using `trigger()`.  The eventhandler invokes the custom event again and again while data contains items.  Thus, the UI is not blocked but table rows begin to appear immediately.

In my case, the web app is running on an intranet, and the local database can return 10,000 rows on the LAN in the blink of an eye, but it takes a good number of seconds for all 10,000 rows to be  created in the HTML Table using knockout for-each binding. With the event approach, the rows start becoming visible to the user instantly.

```
$(document).on("PushIt", function (event, data, results) {

    var item = data.shift();
    var Cust =   new Customer(

                     item["firstname"],
                     item["lastname"],
                     item["addr1"],
                     item["city"],
                     item["state"],
                     item["zipcode"]
        )
    results.push(Cust);
    if (data.length > 0) {
        // timeout avoids recursion-limit problems
        setTimeout(function () { $(document).trigger("PushIt", [data, results]); }, 1);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I developed a custom loading animation for doing this.

```
<!--Preloader-->
    <div id="preloader">
        <div class="preloader" data-bind="visible: _isShow">
            <div class="loader-content">
                <img src="img/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading.." style="margin: 0px auto 20px auto;">
                <br>
                <span class="loader-txt">Loading... Please wait....</span>
            </div>
            <!--End of loader-content-->
        </div>
        <!--End of preloader-->
    </div>
```

CSS codes

```
/*****************Preloader******************/
.preloader {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10000;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;

}
.preloader-hidden{
    visibility: hidden;
}
.preloader .loader-content {
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -22px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -75px;
}
.loader-txt {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

Javascript Code for preloader viewmodel

```
function PreloaderViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self._isShow = ko.observable(false);
    self.ShowPreloader = function() {
        self._isShow(true);
    };
    self.HidePreloader = function() {
        self._isShow(false);
    };
}
```

Register the view model as bellow

```
var preloaderVM;
if ($.isEmptyObject(preloaderVM)) {
        preloaderVM = new PreloaderViewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(preloaderVM, document.getElementById("preloader"));
        preloaderVM.HidePreloader();
    }
```

Use it in ajax call like bellow.

```
//Show preloader
preloaderVM.ShowPreloader();
$.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: "json",
                        url: yourServiceUrl,
                        data: searchdata,
                        success: function (data) {
                            //do whatever in data return from ajax call

                            //Hide preloader
                            preloaderVM.HidePreloader();
                        },
                        error: function (error) {
                            console.log(error.responseText);
                            preloaderVM.HidePreloader();
                        }
                    });
```

If you want to change the text showing in pre-loader by defining a property on preloaderviewModel.

Comment: Thank you, Janith, but the problem I'm describing is not coming through clearly.   Please see my EDIT3.

Answer (score 0):

ko way is to use model to drive the view.

If the standard ko bindings are not enough (for instance, if gif animation is not enough for you), create a customised `ko.bindingHandlers`.

An idea ko app hides all DOM manipulation inside `ko.bindingHandlers`.

Here is a template that I use for ajax data loading.

**HTML**

```
<!-- ko if: loading -->
  <!-- show spinner -->
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko ifnot: loading -->
  <!-- show result, your data-bind="foreach: Results" -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

**Javascript**

```
//assume you use self to hold 'this' pointer in viewModel constructor
self.loading = ko.observable(false);

// in your data loading action
self.loadRemoteData = function() {
   //start loading
   self.loading(true);
   $.ajax({
     // ...
     success: function(data) {
       // update Results(data);
     },
     fail: function() { ...},
     complete: function() {
       //finish loading
       self.loading(false);
     }
   });
};
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the ajax `complete` event fires when the ajax fetch finishes, not when the UI rendering finishes. If items are moved from the ajax data into the ko observableArray in a for-next loop, the UI blocks. We have to avoid a loop there and use array.pop() in tandem with a custom event.

Comment: When you play with Results in ajax success callback, no matter how many times you mutate Results, it would not Fire a rendering. The rendering only happen once when loading turns false. If you are facing rendering performance issue due to unneccessary rendering, this is a solution. If you have to wait for multiple ajax calls, group them into a $.when, then set loading to false after all ajax calls finishes.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "play with".  Data returned by ajax fetch have to be put into an observableArray.  If the dataset is very large, putting the items into the observableArray (bound to TBODY with foreach) by iterating ajax data in a loop will cause nothing to be displayed until the loop is finished. Could take 4-8 seconds depending on size.  But if each item is popped from ajax data array, and each pop triggers the custom event that pushes an item into the observableArray, no loop is required, the UI doesn't block, and the large data set starts appearing in the UI instantly.

Comment: Sounds like you have exactly the rendering performance issue. If you push to an observableArray `n` times, the rendering happens `n` times. This is ko, it doesn't have a concept of `runloop` like `Emberjs` and `Angularjs` (they only fire rendering once at end of a `runloop`). In ko, every changes to observableArray fire a rendering immediately. You need to try this solution in practice.

Comment: You mentioned you Results is very large, it means it will render a huge table and most part of the table is not visible to the user because of screen size. You may need to consider a lazy table solution that only rendering visible part into DOM. No matter whether you uses ko, a huge table means many many DOM objects, it's not scalable with unknown size of data, the browser can only handle within a limit.